# How to remove tag <span style=""> using array() in php?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to remove tag  using array().

This's my code:

```
$string = '<span style="font-family: 'Angsana New', serif;">Hello</span>';
$search = array('/<span (.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/');
$replace = array('\\2');
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

This code isn't error. But It's not remove tag.

Comment: Do you want to remove entire html tags? else you can replace span tag into some other tags?

Comment: oh it is an error - and the syntax highlighting tells you exactly what it is.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove html tags. Can you display example code?

Comment: Also, why not just use http://php.net/strip_tags ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code for remove html tags in array values:

you can used single variable to remove tags means you can **[strig_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)**
sample code for remove html :

```
<?php
echo strip_tags("Hello <b><i>world!</i></b>","<b>");
?>
```

and also remove html tags in array method:

```
function stripAllFields(&$fields) {
  foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
         if (is_array($fields[$key])) { stripAllFields($fields[$key]); }
          else { $fields[$key] = strip_tags($value); }
     }
}
```

Here you can remove multi dimension array values also.
And convert html code into bbcode in php :

Refer this url:

**[Refer Link 1](http://digitcodes.com/create-simple-php-bbcode-parser-function/)**

**[Refer Link 2](http://fluxbb.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=3985)**

And also PHP function are present for BBcode create and parser:

[PHP BBCODE_PARSER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-parse.php)

[PHP BBCODE_CREATE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php)

Comment: Thank you. My project is html convert to bbcode. Because I will remove html tags after I will replace bbcode tags as "<b>Hello</b> World!" to bbcode "[b]Hello[/b] World!". Can you introduce me?

Comment: @KemChat.. you asked about how to remove html code in array thats why i answer it..you can edit you question..i updated my answer please check it..

Comment: I can do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Works ok on my system. Issue from what I could tell is your font-family has single quotes making Angsana New a syntax error. Try this:

```
$string = '<span style="font-family: \'Angsana New\', serif;">Hello</span>';
```

Comment: corrected, thanks for the reminder. changed the " to \'